# how to rewrite root url with htaccess but leave all subfolders untouched

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite the root url for my site, but I need that all the stuff stored in subfolder to remain at the very same address... What I have so far is

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/stockroom
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

and it works but I get an error because oldsite.com/stockroom has an iframe that does not get displayed because it picks from oldsite.com/magazzino/index.php which is turned in newsite.com/magazzino/index.php

EDIT: my problem is that the /stockroom page is loaded with an error: [Error] Refused to display 'http://newsite.com/magazzino/index.php' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN, SAMEORIGIN'. (about:blank, line 0). Of course, this depends by the fact that the url of the iframe is rewritten by the htaccess rule, but it shouldn't!!! it should be http://oldsite.com/magazzino/index.php... what am I missing?

I am a newly with htaccess and I would really appreciate some help.

best regards,
Simone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(stockroom|magazzino/) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Can you this in a new browser? `/magazzino/` shouldn't be redirecting now.

Comment: already done in a new browser, but the result is always the same, magazzino gets redirected...

Comment: Definitely not from this rule but you may have some other rule/code making this redirection.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all folders to not get redirected, you can change your regex pattern:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/stockroom
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The `[^/]*` means any number of characters that is *not* a `/`. So no folders will get redirected.

Comment: thanks, but I still get Refused to display 'http://newsite.com/magazzino/index.php' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN, SAMEORIGIN'.
/stockroom calls a page that contains an iframe which looks for /magazzino, but as you can see that address gets updated...